# VTSO Outlook - Application.AdvancedSearch

Tags: .net, outlook, vsto

For the life of me, I cannot get the following filters to return anything

urn:schemas:httpmail:from
urn:schemas:mailheader:from

(also tried the to and cc filters)

I've tried =, like and everything else I can think of. I can get

urn:schemas:httpmail:subject
urn:schemas:httpmail:textdescription

to work just fine. I need to filter by To, From and CC

any ideas?! Trying to filter mail items using Advanced Search

Edit: Just got urn:schemas:httpmail:fromemail and urn:schemas:httpmail:fromname to work but i'd like to have a single field which contains both name and email "John Smith"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no MAPI property that stores both the SMTP e-mail address and display name in one value.  You have to use both PR_SENDER_EMAIL_ADDRESS_W (http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0C1F001F) and PR_SENDER_NAME_W (http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0C1A001F).

A good trick is to test your filter within a View, and when it's getting the items you expect you can view the DASL filter that's used behind the scenes on the SQL tab:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/philliphoff/archive/2008/12/19/finding-dasl-property-names.aspx

Comment: this helped a lot. I really only NEED to filter on email address values so I can live without the combined data but what about CC? In the filter dialog only uses displaycc which only includes names not email addresses but cc doesn't return anything.

Comment: and whats the deal with not contains? it's written as <> 'value' but neither that nor <> '%value%' works correctly. ideas?

Comment: There's PR_DISPLAY_CC_W and PR_DISPLAY_BCC_W, but it only uses the display name and not the e-mail address.  You'll have to loop through the Recipients collection for each message beyond the initial filter for an ugly second-level filter.

Comment: Oh, and sorry - can't help you with Boolean SQL logic - makes my head hurt.

Comment: thanks. I'm already working on the second level filtering. Oh well.